# Estimate shipping costs in offline mode from historical results

Tags: fedex, ups

Occasionally FedEx or UPS may be unavailable to my app servers, or I need to process 100s of packages for a single transaction.

In these cases an estimate is better than nothing.

Currently I cache results for the exact parameters and "rounded" parameters, eg from_zip[:2], round(weight, 10)

What techniques should I look at to do better than this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that a better approach would be to use some kind or [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) to perform a [proximity search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) of the target price. It can be as simple as finding 2 bounding "points" and interpolating the price of the target point, probably also using a "distance" threshold to not generate too "wild" guesses.

Either way, it's very important to inform the users that the prices are *estimates*, and subject to change.

Comment: Thanks, I will add interpolation to the techniques I'm trying. I've also implemented a stochastic optimizer to find the best coefficients to various equations relating package weight and distance and falling back to nearby results when exceeding a certain distance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using distance, just use a zone lookup table. You should be able to download a zone chart for your account plus associated rates to create a simpler lookup.